# cmake check if a public field exist in class

Tags: cmake, cmake-modules

```
// some_library.h
class MyLib {
  public:
  int field_a;
  int field_b; // Only available on some versions
  int field_c; // Only available on some versions
  int ...;
};
```

A library I'm using have a variable number of public fields depending on versions.
In Cmake, is it possible to detect if a certain field from library header exists?
(perhaps similar to the `CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS`)

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckTypeSize.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You can use `check_symbol_exists` for a C symbol.</strike>

Doc: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckSymbolExists.html

Or `check_cxx_symbol_exists` for a CXX symbol.

Doc: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/module/CheckCXXSymbolExists.html

You can use check_struct_has_member from CheckStructHasMember. See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckStructHasMember.html

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
include(CheckStructHasMember)
Check_struct_has_member("class MyLib" field_a ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/MyLib.h HAS_FIELD_A LANGUAGE CXX)
```

Comment: How would I express a field name? (I know for function symbol, it's easy). Would `MyLib::field_b` just work? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry check_cxx_symbol_exists was wrong for class members. I edited my answer with a tested solution ;)

Comment: Oh wow! That's neat! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!